# Login loop after upgrade

Tags: upgrade, login

After upgrading to Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS

When trying to log on the computer, I am caught in a login loop. I enter the right password, it logs in and gets back right away to the login again

I can login via command line as root, or on webmin as root

I notice a few elements at 100%. Is this related?

```
/dev/loop0         101888     101888          0 100% /snap/core/11993
/dev/loop1           9344       9344          0 100% /snap/canonical-livepatch/126
```

How can I solve this?

ALSO I see this in /var/log/auth.log

```
Dec 22 08:54:56 server50 lightdm: pam_unix(lightdm:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=:0 ruser= rhost=  user=server
Dec 22 08:54:59 server50 lightdm: PAM unable to dlopen(pam_kwallet.so): /lib/security/pam_kwallet.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Dec 22 08:54:59 server50 lightdm: PAM adding faulty module: pam_kwallet.so
Dec 22 08:54:59 server50 lightdm: PAM unable to dlopen(pam_kwallet5.so): /lib/security/pam_kwallet5.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Dec 22 08:54:59 server50 lightdm: PAM adding faulty module: pam_kwallet5.so
Dec 22 08:54:59 server50 lightdm: pam_succeed_if(lightdm:auth): requirement "user ingroup nopasswdlogin" not met by user "server"
Dec 22 08:55:04 server50 lightdm: pam_unix(lightdm-greeter:session): session closed for user lightdm
Dec 22 08:55:04 server50 lightdm: pam_unix(lightdm:session): session opened for user server by (uid=0)
Dec 22 08:55:04 server50 systemd: pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session opened for user server by (uid=0)
Dec 22 08:55:04 server50 systemd-logind[1111]: New session c6 of user server.
Dec 22 08:55:04 server50 systemd-logind[1111]: Removed session c5.
Dec 22 08:55:05 server50 lightdm: PAM unable to dlopen(pam_kwallet.so): /lib/security/pam_kwallet.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Dec 22 08:55:05 server50 lightdm: PAM adding faulty module: pam_kwallet.so
Dec 22 08:55:05 server50 lightdm: PAM unable to dlopen(pam_kwallet5.so): /lib/security/pam_kwallet5.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Dec 22 08:55:05 server50 lightdm: PAM adding faulty module: pam_kwallet5.so
Dec 22 08:55:05 server50 lightdm: pam_unix(lightdm-greeter:session): session opened for user lightdm by (uid=0)
Dec 22 08:55:05 server50 systemd: pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session opened for user lightdm by (uid=0)
Dec 22 08:55:05 server50 systemd-logind[1111]: New session c7 of user lightdm.
Dec 22 08:55:05 server50 systemd-logind[1111]: Removed session c6.
Dec 22 08:55:06 server50 lightdm: PAM unable to dlopen(pam_kwallet.so): /lib/security/pam_kwallet.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Dec 22 08:55:06 server50 lightdm: PAM adding faulty module: pam_kwallet.so
Dec 22 08:55:06 server50 lightdm: PAM unable to dlopen(pam_kwallet5.so): /lib/security/pam_kwallet5.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Dec 22 08:55:06 server50 lightdm: PAM adding faulty module: pam_kwallet5.so
Dec 22 08:55:06 server50 lightdm: pam_succeed_if(lightdm:auth): requirement "user ingroup nopasswdlogin" not met by user "server"
Dec 22 08:57:37 server50 sshd[6916]: rexec line 16: Deprecated option UsePrivilegeSeparation
Dec 22 08:57:37 server50 sshd[6916]: rexec line 19: Deprecated option KeyRegenerationInterval
Dec 22 08:57:37 server50 sshd[6916]: rexec line 20: Deprecated option ServerKeyBits
Dec 22 08:57:37 server50 sshd[6916]: rexec line 31: Deprecated option RSAAuthentication
Dec 22 08:57:37 server50 sshd[6916]: rexec line 38: Deprecated option RhostsRSAAuthentication
Dec 22 08:57:37 server50 sshd[6916]: reprocess config line 31: Deprecated option RSAAuthentication
Dec 22 08:57:37 server50 sshd[6916]: reprocess config line 38: Deprecated option RhostsRSAAuthentication
Dec 22 08:57:41 server50 sshd[6916]: Accepted password for root from 192.168.8.107 port 55828 ssh2
Dec 22 08:57:41 server50 sshd[6916]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Dec 22 08:57:41 server50 systemd: pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Dec 22 08:57:41 server50 systemd-logind[1111]: New session 85 of user root.
```

Thanks!

Comment: The loop devices use NO actual disk space directly; fyi: my own system is installed on a 27GB / partition but if I tally up the different mount points it's closer to 27TB for me mostly due network mounts.  I'd login via text terminal and verify you have space in $HOME or your user directory, as lack of space there and GUI logins cannot succeed thus logout occurs without message (ie. loop). Have you allocated the minimum 25GB recommend if it's a desktop install (minimum since Ubuntu 17.10 thus including 18.04)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)

Answer (score 0):

I Still don't understand why I have  FULL 100% directories now. I guess I will open another post about it.

As for login, it's solved.
The problem was with .Xauthority
Solved with:
connect en tty Ctrl+Alt+F3 than login with user you can't access to GUI interface Ubuntu, command #mv  .Xauthority  .Xauthority.back